# Reading Log from android app through Robotium test project

Tags: android, testing, automation, robotium, event-log

I need to read the logs from the android application project through robotium test project. Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the logs , Please use logcat, in Eclipse(that comes with android SDK).

Go To:

Window --> Show View --> other --> search LogCat

In LogCat you can see the logs for both Application under test and your test project. To use android's inbuilt logging library , you can do something like `Log.d ("I am a Log");`
In LogCat you can filter your preferred logs by creating a filter by clicking on the + button there.

If you want to wait for some log to appear or assert some log messages use the following methods:

```
solo.waitForLogMessage(String logMessage, int timeout);
```

Comment: Most Welcome :)
Please accept the answer , if it helped you out to solve your problem.